# removing entire row containing a Nan value in a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays in python,features array(which is a 4D) and labels array(which is a 1D).The features array contains Nan values. I want to remove the entire row containing the Nan value(in the features array) and its corresponding label. X is the features array and Y is the label array.
I am using isnan function in python as

```
x=x[~np.any(np.isnan(x), axis=3)]
```

when I put axis=1 i get an error

```
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5
```

when I put 3 as shown in the code the codes run without an error and when I check the output array it doesn't have the Nan values anymore but the first three dimensions of the array are collapsed resulting into a 2D array.
any help will be appreciated. 
lets say this one of the rows :

```
[[[[  1.70204959   1.52199801   1.90457233 ...,   1.93644699   1.88296615
  2.19928936],[1.52334234 1.338273......Nan 2.23324432]]]].
```

if the row contains a non value,the whole row should be removed(not just the Nan value),So with this example we should remain with :

```
[[[[  1.70204959   1.52199801   1.90457233 ...,   1.93644699   1.88296615
  2.19928936]]]]
```

only. Also the corresponding label of the removed row will be removed too.

Comment: What do you mean by entire row? the row and columns for me are concepts existing in 2D arrays but I don't see them il 4D arrays. Do you have an example?

Comment: You need to explain in bit more detail on what do you mean removing a row in a 4D array case. A sample case might help you convey the message across.

Comment: I think it would make sense, if you use a 3D **minimal** sample data and show us the expected output. Also, please use the `edit` link to add these details into the question, rather than putting into comments that are not readable.

Comment: @dm5 Please update your question (by using the *edit* link) instead of providing extra information in the comments.

Comment: Let me suggest you something that you could use to create a sample data : `x = np.random.rand(2,3,2,3)` and then let's say we random elem to `NaN` : `x[0,2,1,2] = np.nan`. Now, if you can show us `x` and the expected output, that might help us understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then what you trying to achieve is - sadly - not possible in general.

Let's say you have a 10x10x10 cube and want to remove 3 rows of 10 elements each. This  would leave you with 97 rows and since 97 is prime there is now way but to flatten the non-row dimensions into one.

Since it is obvious that this kind of thing can happen at 4d or any higher dimensionality, that is more or less it.

As a general rule you can keep the ndim only if your mask is 1d, i.e. if you are removing ndim-1 sized subspaces.

```
features = np.random.random((10,9,8,7))
features[features<0.002] = np.nan
mask = np.any(np.isnan(features), axis = (0,2,3))
features[:, ~mask, ...].shape
# (10, 4, 8, 7)
```

As you can see in order to keep 4 dims you have to reduce along **3** axes. (0,2,3) in this example. The axis not occuring in this list - (1) in this case - is the one that will be shortened.

Which of the axes will be the one to be shortened is your choice, just call `any` with all the remaining axes to create the appropriate mask.

Comment: I was able to this after reshaping the dimensions to 2D from 4D,but if I can do it in 4D will be great

Comment: Hi @dm5 I've described a bit what I believe is the only way to keep 4d.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `x.shape` is `(1,1,m,n)` . Ways to do that can be,with `valid=~any(np.isnan(x),3)` :

```
x[:,:,valid.squeeze()]
```

which preserve the 4D, or

```
x[valid].reshape(1,1,-1,x.shape[3])
```

which reconstruct it.